# Looking for an explicit expression of $\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(x/k)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let be $x\in \Bbb R$ and $n \in \Bbb N*$, there are various ways including the use of Fourier series to calculate e.g. $\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(kx)$ or $\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(kx)/k$, as well as the evaluation of the corresponding infinite sums.

Now I am puzzled and stuck by this one, which looks of equivalent complexity, yet obviously of very different nature : $$\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(x/k)$$

I would appreciate any hint to calculate it.

Comment: Why do you think there is a nice formula? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+sin%28x%2Fk%29+k+from+1+to+n

Comment: Well, just my Candide feeling, I would be surprised not to find anything playing with complex numbers and/or power series - but my toolbox is limited

Comment: There is not closed-form. You  can use methods like Euler-Maclaurin summation.